# curl_multi_exec() not requesting all

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

I am trying to use curl_multi_exec() in php with about I am guessing 4000 post calls and getting the return (json). However, After 234 records in my results, my print_r starts showing nothing. I can change the post call url's since each of my URLs has a different postfield, but I would still get 234 results. Does anybody know if there are any limits to curl_multi_exec(). I am using an xampp server on my computer to retrieve the json off a remote server. Is it an option in my xampp install that is preventing more results or a server end limits on my connections?

Thanks. My code for the function is below. The function takes in input $opt which is an array of the curl options.

```
$ch = array();
$results = array();
$mh = curl_multi_init();

foreach($opt as $handler => $array)
{
    //print_r($array);
    //echo "<br><br>";
    $ch[$handler] = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch[$handler],$array);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$handler]);
}
$running = null;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
}
while ($running > 0);
// Get content and remove handles.
foreach ($ch as $key => $val) {
    $results[$key] = json_decode(curl_multi_getcontent($val),true);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $val);
}
curl_multi_close($mh);
return $results;
```

Comment: 4000 post call!!! check `curl_multi_info_read()` also the timeout can be the cause

Comment: `curl_multi_exec` has no limit to number of requests. But the remote server definitely might (and even must!) have such limit